# What will happen at a different aspect ratio and what is the most efficient and easy way of dealing it?

Tags: android, unity, aspect-ratio

Let's say I have built a game for Android at the size of 480x854. If I test this on my device that has this resolution I suppose it will work and look property. But at a different aspect ratio will the game work and look good? Also, what is the most efficient and easy way to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can change aspect ratio without changing resolution. Aspect ratio is the relation between X resolution and Y resolution.

Comment: Yeah, sry. i know that. It was just a syntax error. What i mean is how to handle different aspect ratios (dont mind the different resolution)